# Prolog Ending a Recursion

Tags: prolog

```
 countdown(0, Y).
 countdown(X, Y):-
    append(Y, X, Y),
    Y is Y-1,
    countdown(X, Y).
```

So for this program i am trying to make a countdown program which will take Y a number and count down from say 3 to 0 while adding each number to a list so countdown(3, Y). should produce the result `Y=[3,2,1].` I can't seem the end the recursion when i run this and i was wondering if anyone could help me?

I cant seem to get this code to work any help? I seem to be getting out of global stack so I dont understand how to end the recursion.

Comment: Your second clause needs `X > 0` since it only applies under those conditions.

Comment: Even adding X>0 I still get out of Global Stack error.

Comment: Note that `append` should generally take list arguments. What are you trying to use `append` for? Also, `Y is Y-1` will ALWAYS fail since `Y` and `Y-1` values can never be the same`. You need a new variable, `Y1 is Y-1, countdown(X, Y1)`. You are continually backtracking to `append`, which is generating infinite number of results. Thus, the stack overflow.

Comment: I am trying to make a List Y and each run of the program is suppose to take X and put it into Y and then minus 1 from X so if X=3 Y at the end should be Y=[3,2,1].

Comment: Append does not take an element and append it to a list. It appends two lists resulting in a 3rd list.

Comment: how would one put an element to the end of a list then?

Comment: You could use `append(Y, [X], NewList)`. That takes list `Y` and appends the list of one element `[X]` giving `NewList`. Note that you cannot modify a variable in a prolog clause without backtracking. So you need a new variable for the result. There's a better approach, not using `append`, as @gusbro is showing in his answer.

Comment: You are changing your program permanently which makes your question useless for future visitors. Please don't or add the improved version separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

- first clause does not unify Y.
- second clause uses append with first and third argument Y, which would only succeed if X=[].
- in that clause you are trying to unify Y with another value which will always fail.
- Y should be a list (according to your comment) in the head but you are using it to unify an integer.

You might do it this way:

```
countdown(X, L):-
  findall(Y, between(1, X, Y), R), 
  reverse(R, L).
```

`between/3` will give you every number from 1 to X (backtracking). Therefore `findall/3` can collect all the numbers. This will give you ascending order so we `reverse/2` it to get the descending order.

If you want to code yourself recursively:

```
countdown(X, [X|Z]):-
  X > 1,
  Y is X-1,
  countdown(Y, Z).
countdown(1, [1]).
```

Base case (clause 2) states that number 1 yields a list with item 1.

Recursive clause (first clause) states that if X is greater than 1 then the output list should contain X appended with the result from the recursive call.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new at prolog, Could you explain how this adds the new elements to the list because when i read this my mind is telling me the result would be [1,2,3] instead of what its getting [3,2,1]

Comment: You have to see how this will perform the recurson. When you call it with `3`, it will recursively call itself again with `2` and then with `1`. Then the base case unifies the second argument with `[1]` and returns to the caller which also returns unifying the second argument of the head with `[2|Z]` where now `Z` is `[1]` giving  `[2,1]`. Then again it returns to the caller which again unifies the second argument; this time with `[3|Z]` where now `Z` is `[2,1]` thus giving you the final result of `[3,2,1]`.

Comment: Ah Thank you completely makes sense now, one last question, does the countdown(1,[1]). have to be the second clause? it shouldnt matter if i place it first right?

Comment: Right, I put it as the second clause so that the top-level interpreter i'm using would not leave a choicepoint which will eventually fail (as if X=1 then the recursive step will fail when checking X>1 ).

Comment: Then does that mean i can skip the base case if i change it from X>1 to X/=1 ?

Comment: No, in every recursive procedure you will need one or more base cases, otherwise it will never end recursion or alternatively always fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code

```
countdown( 0 , Y ) .
countdown( X , Y ) :-
  append(Y, X, Y),
  Y is Y-1,
  countdown(X, Y).
```

has some problems:

1. `countdown(0,Y).` doesn't unify `Y` with anything.
2. `Y is Y-1` is trying to unify `Y` with the value of `Y-1`. In Prolog, variables, once bound to a value, **cease to be variable:** they become that with which they were unified. So if `Y` was a numeric value, `Y is Y-1` would fail. If `Y` were a variable, depending on your Prolog implementation, it would either fail or throw an error.
3. You're never working with lists. You are expecting `append(Y,X,Y)` to magically produce a list.

A common Prolog idiom is to build lists as you recurse along. The tail of the list is passed along on each recursion and the list itself is *incomplete*. A *complete* list is one in which the last item is the atom `[]`, denoting the empty list. While building a list this way, the last item is *always* a variable and the list won't be complete  until the recursion succeeds. So, the simple solution is just to build the list as you recurse down:

```
countdown( 0 , []    ) .    % The special case.
countdown( N , [N|Ns] ) :-  % The general case: to count down from N...
  N > 0 ,                   % - N must be greater than 0.
  N1 is N-1 ,               % - decrement N 
  countdown(N1,Ns)          % - recurse down, with the original N prepended to the [incomplete] result list.
  .                         % Easy!
```

You might note that this will succeed for `countdown(0,L)`, producing `L = []`. You could fix it by changing up the rules a we bit. The special (terminating) case is a little different and the general case enforces a lower bound of `N > 1` instead of `N > 0`.

```
countdown( 1 , [1]    ) .
countdown( N , [N|Ns] ) :-
  N > 1 ,
  N1 is N-1 ,
  countdown(N1,Ns)
  .
```

If you *really wanted* to use `append/3`, you could. It introduces another common Prolog idiom: the concept of a *helper* predicate that carries state and does all the work. It is common for the helper predicate to have the same name as the "public" predicate, with a higher arity. Something like this:

```
countdown(N,L) :-   % to count down from N to 1...
  N > 0 ,           % - N must first be greater than 0,
  countdown(N,[],L) % - then, we just invoke the helper with its accumulator seeded as the empty list
  .                 % Easy!
```

Here, `countdown/2` is our "public predicate. It calls `countdown/3` to do the work. The additional argument carries the required state. That helper will look like something like this:

```
countdown( 0 , L , L ) . % once the countdown is complete, unify the accumulator with the result list
countdown( N , T , L ) . % otherwise...
  N > 0 ,                % - if N is greater than 0
  N1 is N-1 ,            % - decrement N
  append(T,[N],T1) ,     % - append N to the accumulator (note that append/3 requires lists)
  countdown(N1,T1,L)     % - and recurse down.   
  .                      %
```

You might notice that using `append/3` like this means that it iterates over the accumulator on each invocation, thus giving you O(N<sup>2</sup>) performance rather than the desired O(N) performance.

One way to avoid this is to just build the list in reverse order and reverse that at the very end. This requires just a single extra pass over the list, meaning you get O(2N) performance rather than O(N<sup>2</sup>) performance. That gives you this helper:

```
countdown( 0 , T , L ) :- % once the countdown is complete,
  reverse(T,L)            % reverse the accumulator and unify it with the result list         
  .                       %
countdown( N , T , L ) :- % otherwise...
  N > 0 ,                 % - if N is greater than 0
  N1 is N-1 ,             % - decrement N
  append(T,[N],T1) ,      % - append N to the accumulator (note that append/3 requires lists)
  countdown(N1,T1,L)      % - and recurse down.   
  .                       %
```